# Connect my laptop through desktop to internet

Tags: linux, networking, ip, connection-sharing

I'm currently at work and our wifi is down. I usually connect my desktop to the internet through eth0 and my laptop connects through wifi.

I have an extra port on the back of the desktop (eth1) and one on my laptop (eth0). I tried connecting a crossover cable between these two ports and bringing up a connection.

I set up a route to the desktop through my laptop and I can ping between the two machines but neither one will connect to the internet through desktop's eth0.

Any help is much appreciated =)

Comment: I assume that your desktop is running Linux (the most common unix variant). Network setup differ too much for a variant-agnostic question to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can set up IPv4 connection sharing manually on a Linux machine. On the router (the desktop), enable packet forwarding, set up [masquerading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on the Internet-facing interface (`eth0`), and use a private IP range on the local interface (`eth1`). Run these commands as root:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ifconfig eth1 up 10.1.1.1 broadcast 10.1.1.255 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

On the laptop, you can set up a static address and route (`eth0` being the wired interface):

```
ifconfig eth0 up 10.1.1.2 broadcast 10.1.1.255 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 10.1.1.1
```

To avoid having to set up anything special on the laptop, you can run a DHCP server on the desktop. For example, install [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) and enable its built-in DHCP server by editing `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to include the following lines:

```
except-interface=eth0
dhcp-range=10.1.1.128,10.1.1.254,24h
```

Note that Network Manager may interfere with these instructions. If you're running it on the router, either stop it or read the [Ubuntu community Internet Connection Sharing page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing). (Network Manager on the laptop isn't a problem.)

If you want these settings to persist after a reboot, this is somewhat distribution-dependent. On Debian and derived distributions, put the following line in `/etc/sysctl.d/connection-sharing.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and the following lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.1.1.1
    broadcast 10.1.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: +1. Would I be correct in summarizing these instructions as configuring the desktop as a router? An alternative to the OP would be to buy a router and hook both machines up to that.

Comment: @Faheem: “On the router (the desktop) …” Strictly speaking, `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and having two interfaces makes the desktop a router; the iptables command makes it a NAT appliance.

Comment: @Gilles: I was not aware there was a precise definition of a router, and have not heard of a NAT appliance previously. Can you provide definitions or references? Thanks.

Comment: @Faheem: 20 years ago, there were sharp differences, because network equipment tended to be expensive and differentiated. Nowadays the difference between a $50 appliance and a $500 appliance is not features but size (bandwidth, number of simultaneous connections, …). So the terminology has become quite blurred, and “router” is an acceptable generic term for many things. “NAT appliance” isn't established terminology. I suggest Wikipedia for generally accepted terminology.

Comment: This worked flawlessly! The only change I made was mimicking desktop's resolv.conf on my laptop. I have some reading to do with iptables :) If you know off the top of your head, could the same be accomplished using the iproute2 utilities WITHOUT iptables? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @kisplit: Right, you'd have to do that if you were using DHCP before and aren't using it now. I don't think you can set up nat without iptables, is there any particular reason you'd want to?

Comment: I was just curious. I don't know anything about iptables other than it uses netfilter (which is a kernel service I think?). I wasn't sure if iproute2 utilities could make use of that kernel service.

Answer (score 0):

Use nice and easy to configure tool - shorewall.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with teZeriusz: Shorewall is a quick and easy way to configure and manage a router ([Documentation here](http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm))